# Google spreadsheets sorting confusion when using formulas

Tags: worksheet-function, sorting, google-sheets

I am sort of confused about the behavior when sorting by a columns content. I have this formula in A1:

```
={"Page";arrayformula(iferror(filter(Events!A16:A,Events!C16:C="Feedback R"),""))}
```

I get the list fine, but if I go and sort the column Z - A, it works but only for a second, then the formula seems to regenerate the list in A - Z order again.

Should I write the formula in some other fashion or am I misunderstanding something about spreadsheets in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that formulas are recalculated automatically. Formulas that use built-in functions are recalculated when the spreadsheet is opened and every time that a change is made.

Instead of using the sort functions of the UI, you could include in your formula SORT (the built-in function), rebuild your formula and use QUERY (another built-in function) or to do a copy & paste only values to another place and use the sort function of the UI in that place.

Another alternative is to use Spreadsheet Freezer (it's a Google Sheets add-on that I published as unlisted in 2019 and very recently I made public; Google Sheets add-ons are free)

Related

- [How do I install Spreadsheet Freezer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129211/88163)
- [How can I allow results from a Google Sheets 'filter' action to be mutable?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129781/88163)