# speed up google sheet with large pivot table

Tags: google-sheets

I have several pivot tables that present 5-7 columns of data extracted from a sheet that has about 30 column and 5000 rows.

That sheet in turn is updated everytime a line is entered in the orders sheet.

I'm finding unacceptable response time from my spread sheet, I think due to the cascade of calculations involved.

There is no way to effectively control the frequency of update in google sheets.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129068/88163

Answer (score 3):

One trick that helps a lot is to shuffle the pivot analysis off into another file

File 1 does your data entry, and contains your static files for lookups.

File 2 uses one or more IMPORTRANGE, one for each sheet it needs from file 1.

Instead of updating every minute or on every change, IMPORTRANGE runs every 30 minutes.  Since I didn't need Real Time pivot tables this was an acceptable answer.

If you *do* need results quickly after making changes in file 1, simply reload the browser tab that has file 2.