# Does Google Sheets do "lazy" calculation?

Tags: google-sheets

E.g. - In gnu make, the program keeps a dependency tree for what files depend on what other files.  So if one file is changed make doesn't have to 'make world'.

In Sheets does it keep a topological sort of cell dependencies so to do the minimum recalculation?

Example:

[image]

Will sheets spend time doing the lower part of the orange box?

If the data in the yellow box changes, will ONLY those cells dependent on the yellow box be recalculated?

Comment: Questions about the web app algorithms and technologies are off-topic here. I don't know if there is a [se] site that this might me on topic as is but I think that on [meta.so] and [meta.codereview.se] might be good places to ask for help to write related questions i.e. ask how to debug / measure / improve spreadsheet performance.

Comment: Related [How do I find out what is slowing down google sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136635/88163), [Google spreadsheet computation load distribution with multiple computers?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124486/88163)

Comment: Anyway, what I think is that the answer is it depends on the formulas, but we could say that the answer for the most common cases is ***yes**, sheets spend time calculating everything every time that a cell **is edited***. Exceptions are, among others, IMPORTsomething (i.e. IMPORTRANGE), and custom functions.

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76448/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129068/88163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sheets only calculates a formula when the data it refers to changes. In other words, if the data in the yellow box changes, only the cells dependent on the yellow box will be recalculated.

The exception is with volatile functions like `indirect()`, `rand()` and `now()` that are recalculated *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet changes.

To improve spreadsheet performance, see [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).